# Single taxonomy attached Multiple post type. can't get post type in taxonomy page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

So I have created one taxonomy called **Problems** its attached to three different post type like(clinic, medispa, skincare).

And I Have created terms for taxonomy(problems) like (clinic, Medispa, Skincare) in admin.

The terms are assigned in primary navigation and its shown also. and created one common taxonomy page for all taxonomy (taxonomy.php)

When I click any taxonomy ex: Clinic in primary nav , I get the loaded taxonomy details using

```
get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )   );
```

its working fine.
**Now my questions is**
I cant get the post type in the loaded term

i use get_post_type() its  not worked 
then how can i get post type for loaded term?

Answer (score 0):

get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) ;
this code use in taxonomy page